# GIT similar to SVN Show log and export - Netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans, repository

on SVN (TortoiseSVN), to pass to production, I usually do:
- Show log;
- Select revision;
- Select files and export them.

This wil give me the modified files for revision selected with tree structure, so easily pass to production.

So, I have searched and found something similiar in GIT, this command:
`git archive -o revisionxpto.zip 8cf4578 $(git diff --name-only 8cf4578^..8cf4578)`

This command do what I want but, can I do this with git plugin (v1.16.2.1) on Netbeans (8.02) or can I do it only on console?

If only on console, there's a better command that the above one?

Thanks in advance for reading.

Best regards,
Marcelo

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best anwser I arrive is using the console on netbeans with, for example, this command (creat a zip, with tree, with diferences from master to feature 33313):

```
git archive --output=feature_33313.zip HEAD $(git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT master feature/33313)
```